# Python-jira sign up using google

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

Is that possible to use python-jira using google account to sign in?

Maybe any workaround for that cause people in our company don't have jira accounts they use google

Answer (score 1):

Once JIRA has been configured to use Google Apps as a user directory, you can authenticate using a Google account, but only the Google Apps account not just any Google account. jira-python will authenticate using the same set of users.